# Android Studio - Kotlin - Global Variables and Functions

Tags: android, kotlin, global

I am so, so new to (a) Android, (b) Java and Kotlin, (c) classes, and so much more.
Yet, I trying to get a basic app going (which it is) on my tablet, and I want to have the equivalent of a global variable to use / share between the various activities.
And because I know so little, any of the solutions I find are missing some basic info that I need. So if anyone can help me that would be really nice :)

So, let's say I have two activities, and I want one global variable, e.g. mainNavState

So what I did was the following:
In Android Studio, in the project folder, I right-clicked where the activities are, and selected New -> Kotlin Class File. I called in GlobalStuff.
Not very inspired, I know.
The contents of this new file are:

```
package com.example.myProj

public class GlobalStuff {

    var mainNavState: Int = 0

    public fun get_mainNavState(): Int {
        return mainNavState
    }

    public fun set_mainNavState(newState: Int) {
        mainNavState = newState
    }

}
```

And now I try and use these functions from my activities.

So, in one activity, I do the following:

```
import com.example.myProj.GlobalStuff as glob
```

And then to call the functions:

```
navState = glob().get_mainNavState()
```

although I can't call the 'set' function:

```
glob().set_mainNavState(1)
```

it expects a member declaration.

So this is all basic stuff that I am trying to get a grasp on. AT some stage I can sit down and go through a course on Kotlin methodically etc., but for now I just want to get something basic going.

Things I might be doing wrong:

Perhaps I have created the wrong file TYPE for my global functions? It is a Kotlin Class file.
Perhaps I need to instantiate it somewhere? Since I am defining a class, but not an actual instance of it?

Thanks for any help :)

Garrett

Comment: I think it's going to be very difficult and a lot more time consuming for you to start writing an app without a basic grasp of programming or at least one language. I'd start with some tutorials on how to tackle some more simple Kotlin projects, and then go onto Android development from there. Good luck!

Comment: As a side note, the example you've provided doesn't contain any concrete errors (although isn't valid in practice, as you're instantiating a new `GlobalStuff` for each call). So we might be missing some context.

Comment: Thanks Henry - I have a lot of coding experience, just not in this environment - so when you step in to a new coding world, it can take time to grasp the concepts etc.

Comment: Taking a step back...there are a host of problems you might run into by trying to track Activity stack in a variable. You need to be intimately familiar with Android task affinities and launch modes to have a hope of doing it reliably. IMO, it's too complicated to be worth it. The standard practice nowadays is to use a single Activity and a Fragment stack in that Activity instead. Android Studio also supplies the WYSIWYG navigation editor for managing your app state.

Comment: Thanks Tenfour04 - I had gone thru a demo tutorial using fragments, and it worked out ok as well, so I sure I will eventually revisit that too. For now I am just want to try scratch projects and learn how to use Bluetooth, LTE etc., and eventually start a new project to do all the stuff (correctly)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Kotlin is much simpler. Don't create a class but an object:

```
object GlobalStuff {
    var mainNavState: Int = 0
}
```

And use it like this from another class:

```
GlobalStuff.mainNavState = 1
val x = GlobalStuff.mainNavState
```

Comment: Thanks Mario - that seems to work.
To reference the variable from an activity, I added this to the imports - I suppose that's the easiest way...

import com.example.bigbin03.GlobalStuff.mainNavState as mainNavState


And then I can just use the mainNavState on its own

e.g. mainNavState = 1

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Good luck with your Android journey.

Comment: @MarioHuizinga can I know why this is bad ?

Comment: @MoheTheDreamy it can be a source of bugs and makes testing more difficult. Usually there are better alternatives (but there are exceptions). Check this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/148108